# Remove elements from array where the numeric value contains the same digit more than once

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, filtering, preg-grep

I want to remove the numbers from array which have repeated digits in them.

```
array('4149','8397','9652','4378','3199','7999','8431','5349','7068');
```

to

```
array('8397','9652','4378','8431','5349','7068');
```

I have tried this thing

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $data = str_split($value, 1);
    $check = 0;
    foreach($data as $row => $element) {
        $check = substr_count($value, $element);
        if($check != 1) {
            array_diff($array, array($value));
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: JS or PHP decide or choose both!

Comment: It would be better to go with PHP as I'm using Laravel

Comment: And have you tried something to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Using explode to break in string and checking each digit count in complete number.

Comment: @DharmendraJadon Then add this attempt in your question^ !

Comment: Do all numbers have 4 digits?

Comment: yes all numbers have 4 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array using a regular expression that matches:

- `(.)` any character
- `.*` followed by zero or more characters
- `\1` followed by the first character one more time

Example code:

```
$array = array('4149','8397','9652','4378','3199','7999','8431','5349','7068');

$result = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($number) {
        return !preg_match('/(.).*\\1/', $number);
    }
);

echo implode(', ', $result), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
8397, 9652, 4378, 8431, 5349, 7068
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I first [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) each element into a separate array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). After this I just compare the splitted array with the same array just with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) digits and check if they are the same. If yes I return the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) number otherwise false. And at the end I just filter the elements with false with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) out.

So in other words I just compare these 2 arrays with they are the same:

array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 9
        )

    //...

)
```

array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
            [3] => 9
        )
    //...

)
```

Code:

```
<?php

    $arr = ['4149', '8397', '9652', '4378', '3199', '7999', '8431', '5349', '7068'];
    $arr = array_map("str_split", $arr);

    $result = array_filter(array_map(function($v1, $v2){
        return ($v1 === $v2?implode("", $v1):false);
    }, $arr, array_map("array_unique", $arr)));     

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => 8397 [2] => 9652 [3] => 4378 [6] => 8431 [7] => 5349 [8] => 7068 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever filtering an array by a regex is required, the ideal tool to use is `preg_grep()`.

The pattern will match any (non-newline) character, then match zero or more of any character, then match the first (captured) character.

To retain values which DO NOT contain at least one recurring character, use: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fOTaD))

```
var_export(preg_grep('/(.).*\1/', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT));
// ['8397', '9652', '4378', '8431', '5349', '7068']
```

---

To retain values which contain at least one recurring character, use:

```
var_export(preg_grep('/(.).*\1/', $array));
// ['4149', '3199', '7999']
```